# Why is Angular build prod adding moz to my readonly class selector, why is the class not applied and how can I fix it?

Tags: css, angular, readonly

I am trying to style non readonly text areas. Although it's working fine locally with `ng serve`, the class is not being applied at all when deploying with `ng build --prod`.

This is the CSS code:

```css
.my-class:not(:read-only) {
    ...;
}
```

With `ng serve`, the browser dev console displays the following css:

```css
.my-class[_ngcontent-c11]:not(:-moz-read-only) { 
    ...;
}

.my-class[_ngcontent-c11]:not(:read-only) { 
    ...;
}
```

However, when I use `ng build --prod`, the CSS I get is

```css
.my-class:not(:-moz-read-only),
.my-class:not(:read-only) { 
    ...;
}
```

Unfortunately, the last version is simply not working. The style is not applied to the element. If I use Chrome's override feature and remove the `.my-class:not(:-moz-read-only),` line completely, it works fine.

Why is the code different from `ng serve` to `ng build --prod`, why isn't the style being applied, and what can I do to fix it?

The angular version (project and CLI) I am using is 10.2.0 and I am using SCSS.

Comment: To whoever voted to close the question because it "doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline", can you please explain what guideline this question does not meet? When someone is sentenced to death, they are usually given the reason for the death penalty, as in the crime they committed, or the law they violated. Is it too much to expect the same on stackoverflow?

Comment: Ideally it should work. which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Hello Vimal. Thanks for reading. I've edited the version at the end of the question.